# Text file into PHP array & search for string

Tags: php, arrays, text-files

I've searched long and hard for an answer to doing this & have come up with nothing. I know someone here will have an answer.

First, I get the URL and grab the subsite out of the beginning:

```
<?php
// get page URL
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
// get host name from URL
    $url = preg_replace('(https?://)', '', $pageURL);
    $affUrl = explode('.', $url);
    $aff = $affUrl[0];
?>
```

If the URL is `affiliate1.domain.com`, this returns `affiliate1` as `$aff`.

Next, I have `affiliates.txt` each with a different name on each line:

```
affiliate1
affiliate2
affiliate-3 (yes, this is correct)
```

Then, I read that file into an array:

```
<?php
// read affiliates.txt and create array
    $affs = file("affiliates.txt"); 

// search for affiliate in array
    $inarray = array_search($aff, $affs); // i've tried in_array() also
    if ($inarray !== false) echo '<img src="affiliatelogos/$aff.jpg" class="aff-img" alt="$aff" />';
?>
```

However, even when I hardcode an affiliate name into `array_search()`:

```
    $inarray = array_search('affiliate1', $affs);
```

It returns nothing. **What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each line includes a newline character, you can ignore them by providing a flag to the "file" function:

```
$affs = file('affiliates.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: Ah, even better than my solution of trimming all the values. I didn't know of that option, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: WOO! That did it. **WONDERFUL!**

Answer (score 0):

Try trimming all the values in the array to remove trailing whitespace and new line characters. This is the simplest way of doing it:

```
array_walk($affs, create_function('&$val', '$val = trim($val);'));
```